# compiler through error: no matching function when trying to use vector of std::pair

Tags: c++, qt

In this code a `typdef` for `std::pair` was declared, then `vector` was made using the new typdef. The vector was initialized in constructor initialization list. When trying to use vector `at(index)` function the compiler throw this error:

```
/home/user/compositionwidget/compositionwidget.cpp:53: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::pair<QPainter::CompositionMode, QString> >::at(<unresolved overloaded function type>)’
     imagePainter.setCompositionMode(comp_pair_vector.at(index).first);
                                                              ^
```

---

```
typedef std::pair< QPainter::CompositionMode, QString >  comp_pair ;

class CompositionWidget : public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    CompositionWidget(QWidget * parent = 0) ;

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);

private:
    QImage * dest_image, *src_image ;
    std::vector <comp_pair>  comp_pair_vector;
    comp_pair curr_composition;
};
```

in compositionwidget.cpp file:

```
    CompositionWidget::CompositionWidget (QWidget *parent)
    :QWidget (parent),
      comp_pair_vector
{
          comp_pair(QPainter::CompositionMode_Clear, "CompositionMode_Clear"),
          comp_pair (QPainter::CompositionMode_ColorBurn , "CompositionMode_ColorBurn"),
          comp_pair (QPainter::CompositionMode_ColorDodge , "CompositionMode_ColorDodge")              
}
{
 src_image =  new QImage   ("/home/user/compositionwidget/images/butterfly.gif") ;

}


void CompositionWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event)

{
    qDebug() << "CompositionWidget::paintEvent()........" ;

    QPainter imagePainter (this) ;
    dest_image->scaled(size()) ;
    imagePainter.drawPixmap(0,0, width(), height(),
                            QPixmap::fromImage(*dest_image));

    src_image->scaled(size()) ;
    imagePainter.setCompositionMode(comp_pair_vector.at(index).first);
    imagePainter.drawPixmap(0,0, width(), height(),
                            QPixmap::fromImage(*src_image));
}
```

Comment: Where does `index` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the variable. The `index` is a function in some library that's included. Alternatively, you can do something with the compiler options, but it's not as robust.

Answer (score 0):

The error message gives you the full answer: you're asking for **`std::vector<...>::at(< unresolved overloaded function type >)’**. So, just ask for things that the library provides and you should be fine.